# Como añadir una firma HTML a gmail

Tags: html5, email, gmail, signature

he creado una firma para emails con HTML5 y CSS (embebido en el html, no con un archivo separado) pero no encuentro manera de insertarla en Gmail o en Mail de Windows 10. ¿Alguien sabe cómo hacerlo? Adjunto el código, aunque creo que en esta ocasión no tiene que ver. Muchos tutoriales sugieren abrir la firma en cualquier explorador, copiar la pagina e introducirla en la firma, pero no es una opción que me interese dado las necesidades de este proyecto.

Muchas gracias,

Pedro

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/08ea001456.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>Firma de Email</title>
</head>

<body>

    <main style="display: flex; width: 100%; max-width: 500px; padding: 1rem;">

        <div style="width: 40%; margin-right: 0.5rem;">
            <img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/firma-email-maria-vidal.appspot.com/o/logotipo%20horizontal.png?alt=media&token=6a71782f-54e1-41f2-b591-861568b52581" alt="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: contain;">
        </div>

        <div style="width: 60%; display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-content: center; padding-left: 1em; border-left-style: solid; border-width: thin; border-color: #6c6d72;">

            <div>
                <h1 style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; font-weight: 500; font-size: 1.5rem; margin: 0; color: #6c6d72;">Nombre y Apellidos</h1>

                <h2 style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; font-weight: 300; font-size: 1.2rem; margin: 0; color: #4b6386; margin-top: 0.5rem;">Cargo</h2>

                <a style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; font-weight: 300; font-size: 1rem; margin: 0; margin-top: 0.3rem; text-decoration: none; color: #4b6386;" href="tel: +34 000 000 000">000 000 000</a>
            </div>

            <div style="margin-top: 0.5em; display: flex; align-items: center">
                
                <a target="_blank" href="#" style="margin: 0.5rem; margin-left: 0;"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in" style="font-size: 1.3rem; color: #4b6386"></i></a>
                
                <a target="_blank" href="#" style="margin: 0.5rem;"><i class="far fa-envelope" style="font-size: 1.3rem; color: #4b6386"></i></a>
                
                <a href="#" style="margin: 0.5rem;"><i class="fas fa-phone" style="font-size: 1.3rem; color: #4b6386"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </main>

</body>

</html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: No me deja editar, pero antes que nada dar las buenas noches a todos :)

Comment: Abre el html con un explorador, selecciona el contenido y pégalo en la configuración de la firma. Esto a mi siempre me ha funcionado, y así tengo configurada mi firma en gmail. Ahora si, si es desde la app de Android olvídate, no se puede todavía

Comment: Muchas gracias Óscar, efectivamente es la opción que más respeta el código, aunque se sigue deformando... Seguiré probando